# Setting up package migrations with Behat 3 and Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, behat

I'm working on including Behat 3 in a new Laravel based API, and I'm using the lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel package to handle authentication.

Been having a time getting the Behat setup working (it is now). I don't get why, but seems like I need to migrate the packages both in the beforeSuite and beforeFeature hooks. Seems silly as I should only have to migrate once before all the features run..?

I would like to only migrate once before the suite loads, otherwise the running time is likely to get long as the number of tests grow.

I've been hacking an example for Behat 2.* to work in version 3.

My FeatureContext class currently looks like this:

```
use Behat\Behat\Context\SnippetAcceptingContext;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;

/**
 * Behat context class.
 */
class FeatureContext implements SnippetAcceptingContext
{

    private $_restObject        = null;
    private $_restObjectType    = null;
    private $_restObjectMethod  = 'get';
    private $_client            = null;
    private $_response          = null;
    private $_requestUrl        = null;

    private $_baseUrl           = null;

    /**
     * Initializes context.
     *
     * Every scenario gets its own context object.
     * You can also pass arbitrary arguments to the context constructor through behat.yml.
     */
    public function __construct($baseUrl)
    {
        $this->_restObject  = new stdClass();
        $this->_client      = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $this->_baseUrl = $baseUrl;
    }

    /**
    * @static
    * @beforeSuite
    */
    public static function bootstrapLaravel()
    {
        $unitTesting = true;
        $testEnvironment = 'testing';
        // This assumes the FeatureContext.php class is within app/tests/features/bootstrap
        $app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../../../bootstrap/start.php';

        $app->boot();

        Mail::pretend(true);
    }

    /**
    * @static
    * @beforeSuite
    */
    public static function setUpDb()
    {
        Artisan::call('migrate');

        self::migratePackages();

        /* do seeding */
        $seeders = array(
            "OAuthTestSeeder",
            "RolesPermissionsSeeder"
        );

        foreach ($seeders as $seedClass)
        {
            Artisan::call("db:seed", array("--class" => $seedClass));
        }        
    }
    /**
    * @static
    * @beforeFeature
    */
    public static function prepDb()
    {
        Artisan::call('migrate:refresh');
        self::migratePackages();

        Artisan::call('db:seed');


    }

    public static function migratePackages() 
    {
        $packages = array(
            "lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel",
        );        

        foreach ($packages as $packageName)
        {
            Artisan::call("migrate",
                array("--package" => $packageName, "--env" => "testing"));
            echo 'migrating package: '.$packageName;
        }   

    }
/* feature specs here... 
*/ 
}
```

Comment: I'd help if I knew what you are asking :) Are you trying to migrate the database only once before all the tests start?

Comment: Thanks @IanBytchek I updated the question with a clearer question! 
Yes to answer your question. Also wondering if I am doing it in a sane/efficient way, as its been difficult finding Behat 3 compatible examples.

Comment: Did you work it out in the end?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, documentation and examples are not the strongest part of Behat, but not to fear. Unlike some other testing software Behat doesn't give you that single option for running the bootstrap when you load the whole thing, though it gives a lot of other cool features. You are almost on the right path. All you need to do is to have a static flag that indicates if the bootstrap did the job or not. In my case I made this work by adding `TestUtility` class that stores the state value and SetUpTrait that is included in each context.

```
final class TestUtility extends AbstractUtility
{

    protected static $bootstrapped = false;

    public static function isBootstrapped()
    {
        return self::$bootstrapped;
    }

    public static function bootstrap()
    {
        if (self::isBootstrapped()) {
            return;
        }

        include_once(__DIR__ . './../bootstrap.php');
        self::$bootstrapped = true;
    }
}

trait SetUpTrait
{

    public static function setUpSuite(BeforeSuiteScope $scope)
    {
        TestUtility::bootstrap();
    }
}

class My extends RawMinkContext
{
    use SetUpTrait;
}
```

I managed to set up applications to use single bootstrap file for the app itself, PHPUnit and Behat testing. It carries a few extra lines of code but there is a single entry for everything and its incredibly easy to maintain – definitely easier than having 3 bootstrap files.